# error while trying to install ubuntu mate 18 LTS: "MODSIGN: couldn't get uefi db list"

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I'm trying to install ubuntu Mate 18 LTS on a friend's laptop of model Sony Vaio.

I've checked the usb installer for errors and saw that it works on my laptop.

On similar questions online I see that some recommend turning off secure boot, but I see no such feature in my friend's laptop BIOS.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When you see the error? Are you able to boot live system?

Comment: No, I see it after I select "try without installing". It hangs on a blank screen for a moment and then I get the error

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Add the error message to the body of the question (it is easy to miss in the title) and explain when you see this error.

Comment: Have you tried to boot from live usb with `nomodeset` grub option? Could you post `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdX` - where sdX is you Live USB drive.

Comment: I have tried using nomdeset, it says no such option. I can't post any command, because Linux does not come up

Comment: Seems like this is the case with newer kernels [link](https://medium.com/@maniac.tw/linux-bug-modsign-couldnt-get-uefi-db-list-14a014b7ed54)